# Have Max value of range of dates filter be todays date

Tags: tableau-api, datefilter

I have a "Range of Dates" filter and what I want is for the max (or right most value) to always be the most recent date which should be today's date. What seems to be happening is that if I leave the dashboard open and come back the next day the max value is yesterday's date and I must manually move the slider over to be today's date. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you please leave a little more information on dimensions and measures names used to try to help you about this... maybe a print screen? Regards

Comment: It could be used by getting a Dimension with MAX(date).... and change de Range of Dates filter with a Date filter with condition comparing dates with Dimension with MAX(date).... so is dinamically changing....

Answer (score 1):

I find a calculated field is the best way to do this as I have run into the same issues using the out of the box max date filter.

Create a calculated field as follows:

```
[date] =  {FIXED: max([date])}
```

This creates a True False field where only the records that have the max data and carried through.

Now drag this onto the filter pane and select 'TRUE'.

Answer (score 1):

I've generally seen two basic approaches for this problem: Calculated fields and relative dates.

1. Use a **calculated field** or parameter or some combination of calculated fields and parameters with filters. This is similar to what smb suggests in their answer to this question. It also seems [to](https://community.tableau.com/thread/152179) [be](https://community.tableau.com/thread/111955) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508407/set-the-latest-date-value-to-the-quick-filter-in-tableau) [most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807304/default-range-for-date-range-filter-in-tableau) [popular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986239/max-date-should-appear-automatically-in-tableau-after-extract-refresh) [approach](https://community.tableau.com/thread/254071).
2. If you don't particularly care about being able to set the end-date with the slider, you could try using **[relative dates](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.html#qs_relative_dates.html)**, using the approaches detailed in the accepted answer to [this Tableau forum question](https://community.tableau.com/thread/247381) and in [this Tableau Knowledge Base article](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/range-of-dates-quick-filter-does-not-refresh). Jennifer Vonhagel also gives a second answer to the Tableau forum question farther down that uses a parameter plus calculated field approach.

Additionally, [this Tableau Knowledge Base article](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/setting-default-date-to-most-recent-date-on-a-quick-filter) offers another option (Option 1, in the article) if you have Tableau 10.3+: You can use the **"Latest Date Preset"** (see [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v10.3/pro/desktop/en-us/filtering.html#LatestDatePresets) for details) check box in the date filter dialog box. I haven't used this, but it looks promising if you're using Tableau Desktop (seems like it wouldn't work for Tableau Web). The article's Options 2-4 are just riffs on calculated fields, in my opinion.

Two more approaches I've heard of – but never personally seen in the wild:

1. **Push the max date down into the view** you put Tableau on top of and let the view do the work.
2. [Use a script to **modify the Tableau workbook's XML**](https://community.tableau.com/thread/110548).